# How do I change the way vim autocompletes commands?

Tags: vim

I use the :split in vim all the time, I however neveer uses :spelldump or :spell* in general.

Is there any way to make :split be the first commmand to appear when autocompleting on :sp ?

Comment: For this you don't need autocomplete at all. Just type `:sp` and then Enter.

Comment: my oh my ... all these years of VIM and not knowning... why didnt I ask this 15 years ago -.- Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the comment you don't need to autocomplete for this particular use case, `:sp` will do the trick. If you enter part of a builtin command that is ambiguous, Vim prefers one command over the other:

- **`:s`** could be `:substitute`, `:split`, `:spelldump`, etc., but for Vim it is **`:s[ubstitute]`**
- **`:sp`** could be `:split`, `:spelldump`, `:sprevious`, etc., but for Vim it is **`:sp[lit]`**

In the help this is indicated with square brackets around the optional part of the command just as is shown above.

To answer the general question: I don't think you can change the way Vim autocompletes commands. You can define your own shorter command (which must be uppercase), e.g. `:command! S split`. Or you could define a mapping, e.g. `:nnoremap \s :split<CR>`. Finally, you could use a builtin normal mode command, which for this particular use case is simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd>.